# How to change color back from HSV to RGB

Tags: python, numpy, colors

I am doing a little experiment to debug my project. I am trying to manipulate the hue value on HSV colorspace to see the effect on it when I change it back to RGB.

I have a simple image with whole blue background and a single red circle inside of it. I convert it from RGB to HSV and then change one of the values, and then revert it back to the previous value (please see the code, I can't explain it well by using just words). I was expecting the image to remain the same but to my surprise, when I changed it back from HSV to RGB it gives different image.

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from bqplot import pyplot as bq
import math
import os

ori_image = cv2.imread('../test.png')
image = np.float32(ori_image)
image = cv2.cvtColor(ori_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL)
hues=np.round(image[:,:,0]/255*360)
np.place(hues,hues==229,50)
np.place(hues,hues==50,229)
hues=hues/360*255
temp_image = image.copy()
temp_image[:,:,0]=hues
temp_image=cv2.cvtColor(temp_image,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
plt.imshow(temp_image)
plt.show()
```

Can someone give an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just used the wrong [`ColorConversionCode`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0) for your second conversion. If you use `COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL` for the "forward conversion", you need to use `COLOR_HSV2BGR_FULL` for the "backward conversion". You used `COLOR_HSV2RGB`, which is indeed wrong in two ways: (1) You convert to RGB instead of BGR, and (2) you don't use the full conversion for the H channel.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

orig_image = np.ones((400, 400, 3), np.uint8)
orig_image[:, :, 0] *= 255
orig_image[:, :, 1:3] = 0
cv2.circle(orig_image, (100, 100), 50, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

image = np.float32(orig_image)                                  # this line is ignored either way
image = cv2.cvtColor(orig_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL)
hues = np.round(image[:, :, 0] / 255 * 360)
np.place(hues, hues == 229, 50)
np.place(hues, hues == 50, 229)
hues = np.round(hues / 360 * 255)                               # Use np.round here, too, to prevent integer cutting
temp_image = image.copy()
temp_image[:, :, 0] = hues
temp_image = cv2.cvtColor(temp_image,  cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR_FULL)  # You need to use the proper color conversion code here

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1), plt.imshow(orig_image), plt.title('Original image')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2), plt.imshow(temp_image), plt.title('Modified image')
plt.savefig('C:/Users/c.wilde/Desktop/output.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Note: Matplotlib uses RGB ordering, OpenCV BGR ordering, that's why the blue and red in the plots are inverted.

Also, please notice: I added a rounding at `hues = np.round(hues / 360 * 255)`, because `image` and `temp_image` (before converting to BGR) were slightly different due to "integer cutting"; `image` had mostly values `171`, and `temp_image` mostly values `170`. The main result after converting to BGR was identical, but for the sake of completeness, I wanted to mention that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I am looking for. Can you help me a little more ? What exactly is the difference between not using _FULL and using it?

Comment: For `BGR2HSV`, the range of hue is `[0 ... 180]`, also represented as values `[0 ... 180]` (basically to properly fit in the `uint8` data type without "complicated" scaling). For `BGR2HSV_FULL`, the range of hue is `[0 ... 360]`, but represented as values `[0 ... 255]`, so the exact scaling, you also use, is done to fit `[0 ... 360]` to `[0 ... 255]`.